# Использование циклов в Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, возник следующий вопрос: с клавиатуры вводиться число если оно целое, тогда будет выполняться какой-то код, если нет - выводиться строчка, что число не являеться целым, и вводиться новое. Есть код:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите кол-во интервалов: ");
    if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        while (sc.hasNextInt() == false){System.out.println("Некорректный тип введеного числа! Повторите попытку: ");}
    } else {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
}
```

Если ввожу целое все нормаьно, при вводе к примеру 2.3 работает бесконечный цикл и не могу вводить число. Вопрос пустячный, но подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: Знаю, что вопрос глупый, но тем не менее он возник

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался рекурсией, ниже пример.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myMain();
}

private static void myMain() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите кол-во интервалов: ");
    if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Повторите попытку!");
        myMain();
    } else {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

написал ещё один вариант без рекурсии, вот пожалуйста

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc;
    System.out.print("Введите кол-во интервалов: ");
    while (true) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Некорректный тип введеного числа! Повторите попытку: ");
        } else { 
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            sc.close();
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не очень удачное решение. При множестве неправильных попыток будет создано большое количество ненужных объектов.

Comment: @pavlofff, не спорю, но в учебных целях сойдёт ) и да, спс за комент ))

Comment: @Diofloyk, объсните,пожалуйста,Ваш код. Рекурсия - это ведь функция вызывающая саму себя. В данном случае это функция myMain()?

Comment: @MuscledBoy ага, всё верно. Если sc не является int, то просто ещё раз вызывается myMain() и так до тех пор пока вы не введёте значение типа int, ну или как правильно заметил pavlofff, пока у вас не кончиться память отведённая для VM

Comment: @pavlofff, Вы имели в виду ненужные объекты класса Scanner?

Comment: @pavlofff, не будет ли для Вас затруднительным написать свое решение?

Comment: c подачи Hovo сделали цикл правильным )

Comment: @Diofloyk, огромное Вам спасибо. Ваш ответ показался мне самым простым, поэтому его и возьму. Единственное хочу спросить, как правильно толковать условие цикла **while(true)**?

Comment: @Diofloyk, и еще один вопрос: надо ли в этом случае закрывать поток ввода,чтобы он не занимал ресурсы?

Comment: @MuscledBoy условие цикла while(true) можно трактовать как бесконечный цикл. С закрытием потока думаю в данном случае можно не замарачиваться) поправте кто - то если я не прав

Comment: @Diofloyk, прошу прощения за назойливость, понимаю, что в данном случае мы не будем вводить сотни раз неправильные значения, но если смотреть на задание серьезно, то **sc.close();**, введенный перед return; и закроет поток?

Comment: @MuscledBoy ага, лучше закрыть поток. извиняюсь, упустил этот момент )

Comment: @Diofloyk, еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите кол-во интервалов: ");
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Некорректный тип введеного числа: " + scanner.next());
    }
    System.out.println("Введенное целое число: " + scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Именно вызов `scanner.next()` считывает следующий токен, за счет чего, следующий вызов `scanner.hasNextInt()` применится уже к токену, следующему за только что считанным (посредством `scanner.next()`), тем самым, предотращая бесконечный цикл.

---

Ну, или более общий вариант решения (в предыдущем примере по окончанию токенов в консоли будет ожидаться ввод нового без оповещения об этом):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Введите кол-во интервалов: ");
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(consoleScanner.nextLine());
        while (lineScanner.hasNext() && !lineScanner.hasNextInt())
            System.out.println("Некорректный тип введеного числа: " + lineScanner.next());

        if (lineScanner.hasNext() && lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Введенное целое число: " + lineScanner.nextInt());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        boolean isInt = false;
        Scanner sc;
        do {
            System.out.print("Введите целое число: ");
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                i = sc.nextInt();
                isInt = true;
                System.out.println(i);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Некорректный тип введеного числа! Повторите попытку: ");
            }
        } while (!isInt);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня был похожий вариант, но в данном случае не будет возможности ввести новое число

Comment: а что делает метод close(); ?

Comment: @MuscledBoy закрывает поток ввода, чтобы он не занимал ресурсы, когда больше не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

ты с начало проверяешь не является ли число типа int, "if (!sc.hasNextInt())",
а потом зачем то создаешь цикл while где условие то же самое что и в "if (!sc.hasNextInt())". и sc.hasNextInt всегда будет false. поэтому и бесконечный цикл.